# BWToolkit and xcode 3.2.1

Tags: cocoa, xcode, bwtoolkit

I have problem with BWToolkit and XCode. For some reasons Xcode not recognize bwtoolkit framework. IB plugin working fine. I did same steps as described on bwtoolkit site. I did:

1. Download latest bwtoolkit from http://www.brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/
2. Add BWToolkitFramework.framework to Linked frameworks
3. Add BWToolkitFramework to copy target
4. Add `"#import <BWToolkitFramework/BWToolkitFramework.h>"` to my class
5. Got "not such file" build error for BWToolkitFramework/BWToolkitFramework.h

I think it related to Xcode version as I remember it worked on prev Xcode version and when I downloaded Hellium project which used BWtoolkit and build it then no errors, I tried copy most of project settings from helium to my project but result the same(not found build errors)

My env:
Xcode 3.2.1
Snow Leopard

Thanks

Comment: Same environment, same steps, works fine on my system. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Problem was in build settings, not sure what exactly as I'v changed many of them

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a Framework Search Path to the build settings so Xcode knows where to look for it?

To do this, open the project or target settings, and add a path to the framework in the Framework Search Paths section.  Make sure you're adding it to All Configurations.